# ChessAI: Why is recursion of a reference of a class somehow capped?

Tags: c++, recursion, reference, chess

I have made a c++ class to represent a board and i have noticed that if i call a recursive function that has as an argument the reference to a board object, it stops after a while resulting in approx 5000-6000 calls to end condition, even with a depth of 10+

Here is the code of the recurse function, the board, and the output:

Chess.h:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

#include "Utils.h"

#define KING 0
#define QUEEN 1
#define BISHOP 2
#define KNIGHT 3
#define ROOK 4
#define PAWN 5

#define WHITE 0
#define BLACK 1

typedef std::pair<short, short> Tile;

namespace Chess {

    class Piece {

        public:
            short color;
            short type;

            Piece();

            Piece(char fenChr);

            Piece(short pType, short pColor);

    };

    class Board {
        private:
            std::vector<Tile> enpassant;
            bool whiteKingsidecastle = false;
            bool whiteQueensidecastle = false;
            bool blackKingsidecastle = false;
            bool blackQueensidecastle = false;
            short currentPlayer = 0;
            

        public:
            std::array<std::array<Piece, 8>, 8> _board;

            Board(std::string fenStr); // Construct a board object given a fen board

            bool inBoard(Tile t); // Check if there is a piece at a given position (t)

            std::vector<Tile> getPiecesPositions(); // Get all the pieces positions

            bool inEnpassant(Tile t); // Check if a piece at a given position (t) is eligible for enpassant (it's first move and it has moved by two tiles)

            void movePiece(Tile pos1, Tile pos2); // Move a piece at a give position (pos1) to a new position (pos2)

            std::string toFen(); // Return the fen equivalent of the current board

            short getCurrentPlayer(); // Get the color of whoever has the right to move

        
    };

std::vector<Tile> generateLegalMoves(Chess::Board& board, Tile pos) {
        std::vector<Tile> moves;

        short pieceColor = board._board[pos.first][pos.second].color;
        short pieceType = board._board[pos.first][pos.second].type;
        if (pieceColor == -1) return std::vector<Tile>();

        switch(pieceType) {
            case PAWN:
            return Chess::pawnMoves(board, pos);
            case KNIGHT:
            return Chess::knightMoves(board, pos);
            case ROOK:
            return Chess::rookMoves(board, pos);
            case BISHOP:
            return Chess::bishopMoves(board, pos);
            case QUEEN:
            return Chess::queenMoves(board, pos);
            case KING:
            return Chess::kingMoves(board, pos);
            default:
            return std::vector<Tile>();
        }

        
        return std::vector<Tile>();
    }
```

Here is the code of the recursive function:

TestUnit.cpp:

```cpp
int moveGenTest(Chess::Board& board, int depth, short color)
{
    if (depth == 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    int numPos = 0;
    depth -= 1;
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (uint8_t g = 0; g < 8; g++) {
            if (board._board[i][g].color == color) {
                for (Tile move : Chess::generateLegalMoves(board, Tile(i, g))) {
                    board.movePiece(Tile(i, g), move);
                    numPos += moveGenTest(board, depth, !color);
                    board.movePiece(move, Tile(i, g));
                }
                
            }
        }
    }

    return numPos;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Chess.h"
#include "TestUnit.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    Chess::Board board("rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq");

    std::cout << moveGenTest(board, 5, WHITE);
  
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```cpp
5171 // depth 5 - should be around 4 million
5795 // depth 6 - should be around 119 million
```

Comment: Recursion has its limits. Going too far will, ironically enough, result in a stack overflow.

Comment: @Taekahn but why when i remove the reference operator (&) from the function arguments i get the output i want but wayyyy slower (approx 30/40 seconds for a 5 ply deep search)

Comment: @kreaon if you pass the board by value youll be making a *ton* of copies of it, and dynamic allocations are typically expensive so that might have something to do with it. youd have to profile the code to see exactly what takes the bulk of the execution time.

Comment: I did, almost 30% of the cpu time is used to make the copies of the board, and i dont know how make it faster that since most of the functions are not written by me

Comment: If passing the board by value works correctly but by reference doesn’t it strongly suggests that the code for undoing a move isn’t right. Specifically, it doesn’t look like that second call to `movePiece` can handle undoing a capture.